# Django, Path return 404

Tags: python, django

I've got an issue with my Django app, when i try to browse to http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/ it returns a 404 error :

```
Using the URLconf defined in f_django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^contact/$
^description/$
^$
myapp/
admin/
The current path, list/, didn't match any of these.
```

Here my **urls.py** file :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include    
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/$',views.contact),
    url(r'^description/$',views.description),
    url(r'^$',include('myapp.urls')),
    path('myapp/',include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My **myapp/urls.py** file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index),
    url(r'^list',views.list),
    url(r'^Articles/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.details),
]
```

And this line in my **settings.py** :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `'^list'` to `'^list/$'`, having your urls end with a `/` is important because Django appends slashes by default to any incoming url which doesn't end in one. You can change this by setting `APPEND_SLASH = False` in the settings. Also you are including `myapp.urls` twice in your project level urls.
Also in your include:

```
url(r'^$',include('myapp.urls'))
```

You are including urls but in the pattern you write `^$`. In regex `^` means the string should start from that position and `$` means the string should end at that position. Your pattern for views.list end up being `^$^list/$` which is impossible to match. Basically you are preventing any included urls from being matched if you do this. Remove the `$` from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both changes (`^list/$` and removing the double include in `myapp.urls`) and still got the same issue

Comment: @lezogeek Please check I have edited the answer.